# How to add sorting for aggregate results in page block table

Tags: pageblocktable

I have a page block table and added column values specifically instead of referring the whole object as a list.
The requirement is I need to add sorting for all the columns.
I have followed this
[blog page](http://gaganbansalblog4u.com/2013/02/28/pagination-in-visualforce-page-along-with-sorting/)

and added sorting for the columns which I have simply queried from object.

the problem here is,in my pageblock table I have 2 aggregate result fields/coulmns and I need to add sorting functionality to those columns as well.

**Assigning values for all the fields for the first time,**
In the standard controller constructor retrieving the query result in a list and assigning the list to the standard controller as mentioned in the blog.

In the constructor part itself created 2 Map variables and assigned the aggregate query result value to that particular field.

**When I go for sorting,**
For simple sorting(non aggregate result fields) am simply querying the object with asc/desc and assigning the list to the standard controller constructor.

But am unable to use the same procedure for this aggregate result value..

I tried all the ways..Nothing is working for me..

Have anyone faced this kind of scenarios..
Any idea..
I hope am not confusing..If you need any more info I can provide...
Thanks in advance..

Chitra

Comment: If you must do this server side, you need to create a wrapper object for your results and use the comparable interface. Otherwise I think you're best bet may be some javascript UI for the table, that has an easy sort baked in.

Comment: Hi,
I do not need to do it in server side.I have read an option like that.Client side would be better and it won't query the object again & again..The thing is I do not know how to achieve it..

Comment: Try this library: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: These datatable is not working with the boolean values..

Comment: If I use StandardController then the aggregate result sorting is not working.... If am using Enhanced page block table(V-2.25) the boolean sort is not working...If I use Enhanced Pageblock table ADV(V-2.01) then the link field is not getting sorted.That is my first field is Cause Name with hyperlink...I have all these fields in my table...How can I achieve this with a single solution...